Computation of ideal of functions, given by explicit quadratic equations, vanishing on $G/P$ for the exceptional Lie group $G_2.$
In Section 10.6.6 of Procesi's "Lie Groups" he writes that a theorem due to Kostant tells us that for an algebraic group $G$ and a parabolic subgroup group $P,$ the ideal of functions vanishing on $G/P$ is given by explicit quadratic equations.
Fulton and Harris's "Representation Theory" states that:

For the standard representation of $G_2,$ $G_2/P$ is a quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^6.$ i.e. cut out by a single quadric in (at most) 7 variables.
For the adjoint representation, Fulton-Harris claims that $G_2/P$ is contained in
$$\Sigma := \left\{\Lambda\subset V: \omega(\Lambda, \Lambda,\cdot) \equiv 0\right\} \subset G(2, V).$$ Where $V=\mathbb{C}^7$ is the standard representation and $\omega$ is a skew-symmetric trilinear form. I belive it is actualy equal to $\Sigma$.

Is there a reference which explicitly calculates the quadrics for these cases?

Any generalized flag variety $G/P$ is (diffeomorphic to) orbit of line through the highest weight vector in the projectivization of irreducible representation $V_\lambda$ which is determined by $P$.
According to A system of quadrics describing the orbit of the highest weight vector by Lichtenstein such orbits are characterized by
$$
\Omega (v\otimes v) =\langle 2\lambda+2\delta,2\lambda\rangle (v\otimes v)
$$
where $\Omega$ is the Casimir operator and $\delta$ is half the sum of positive roots.

In fact,
$$
G_2/P = \mathrm{Gr}(2,7) \cap \mathbb{P}^{13},
$$
is a highly non-transverse linear section of the Grassmannian. However, still the restrictions to $\mathbb{P}^{13}$ of the Plucker quadrics (defining the Grassmannian) cut out $G_2/P$.
Alternatively, one can use representation theory: one has
$$
\mathrm{Sym}^2V_{\omega_2} = 
V_{2\omega_2} \oplus V_{2\omega_1} \oplus \Bbbk,
$$
hence the ideal of quadrics through $G_2/P$ is generated by the subspace
$$
V_{2\omega_1} \oplus \Bbbk \subset \mathrm{Sym}^2V_{\omega_2}.
$$

When you write $G_2/P=Gr(2,7)\cap\mathbb P^{13}$, do you mean by the Plucker embedding you view $Gr(2,7)$ as a subvariety of $\mathbb P^{20}$ and $\mathbb P^{13}$ is some linear subvariety of codimension $7$?

@KentaSuzuki: Yes, precisely. If $V$ is the 7-dimensional representation of $G_2$ then this is the intersection of $Gr(2,V) \subset \mathbb{P}(\wedge^2V)$ with the projectivization of the space $\mathrm{Ker}(\wedge^2V \to V^\vee)$, where the map is given by a $G_2$-invariant skew-symmetric 3-form.
